# Oracle partitioned table query cost vs non-partitioned table query cost

Tags: oracle, indexing, partitioning, database-administration, database-partitioning

I have a table **PO_HEADER** with ~20 million records. Considering our future load on the table we have decided to partitioned the table to increase the performance of the sql queries. Below are the queries used to create the new partitioned tables.

```
CREATE TABLE PO_HEADER_LP 
 PARTITION BY LIST (BUYER_IDENTIFIER)
(PARTITION GC66287246AA VALUES ('GC66287246AA') TABLESPACE MITRIX_TABLES,
PARTITION GC43837235JK VALUES ('GC43837235JK') TABLESPACE MITRIX_TABLES,
PARTITION GC84338293AA VALUES ('GC84338293AA') TABLESPACE MITRIX_TABLES,
PARTITION DEFAULTBUID VALUES (DEFAULT) TABLESPACE MITRIX_TABLES) 
AS SELECT * 
   FROM PO_HEADER;

create index PO_HEADER_LP_SI_IDX on PO_HEADER_LP("SUPPLIER_IDENTIFIER") TABLESPACE MITRIX_INDEXES LOCAL;
```

Old Table PO_HEADER has two indexes on "BUYER_IDENTIFIER" and "SUPPLIER_IDENTIFIER" columns as follows:

```
create index PO_HEADER_BI_IDX on  PO_HEADER("BUYER_IDENTIFIER") TABLESPACE MITRIX_INDEXES;
create index PO_HEADER_SI_IDX on  PO_HEADER("SUPPLIER_IDENTIFIER") TABLESPACE MITRIX_INDEXES;
```

To test the performance of the query, I executed below query on both the tables. But, to my wonder I saw the cost of the 2nd query is almost double than the 1st one. Can any body know, why is the query cost is high of the partitioned table compared to normal table. Thanks in Advance.

```
select * from po_header where buyer_identifier='GC84338293AA' and supplier_identifier='GC75987723HT'; --cost: 56,941
select * from po_header_lp where buyer_identifier= 'GC84338293AA' and supplier_identifier='GC75987723HT'; --cost: 93,309
```

PO_HEADER with Global Index on buyer_identifier & supplier_identifier column
[image: PO_HEADER with Global Index on buyer_identifier & supplier_identifier column]

PO_HEADER_LP with Global Index on supplier_identifier column
[image: PO_HEADER_LP with Global Index on supplier_identifier column]

PO_HEADER_LP with Local Index on supplier_identifier column
[image: PO_HEADER_LP with Local Index on supplier_identifier column]

Comment: There is a DBA community on stack exchange

Comment: If you were to include the execution plan, that may shed more light than just the cost.

Comment: Comparing the cost of two queries against two different tables is generally not meaningful. There are any number of different statistics that are likely to be different.  Does the query against the partitioned table actually run faster, consume less CPU, do fewer logical reads, etc.?  Are there really only 3 `buyer_identifier` values in the table?  Or are there 3 `buyer_identifier` values that account for large fractions of the rows and a number of others that are much smaller?

Comment: You need to provide both execution plans (**edit** your question, formatted text please, no screen shots)

Comment: Does the new partitioned table also have indexes?

Comment: @Gerrat added pan of the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your DDL I assume, you have three big buyers (say 5M records each) and a bunch of smaller ones. In other word this would be the correct setup for you list partitioning schema.

You may verify, whether it works testing access on buyer only:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into plan_table  FOR
select * from tab_lp where BUYER_ID = 1;
;  
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |        |  6662K|    82M|  4445   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION LIST SINGLE|        |  6662K|    82M|  4445   (2)| 00:00:01 |   KEY |   KEY |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TAB_LP |  6662K|    82M|  4445   (2)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The same query for the non-partitioned table should produce much higher cost. Why?
In the partitioned table the selected buyer (in your case GC84338293AA, I'm using surrogate keys) has it own partition.
So full scan of this partition is the best access.

```
select * from tab where BUYER_ID = 1;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |  6596K|    81M| 14025   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB  |  6596K|    81M| 14025   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("BUYER_ID"=1)
```

For the non-partitioned table (to get approximately one fourth of the data) the FULL TABLE SCAN is OK as well,
but of course **has higher cost** as all data must be scanned.

Note - if you see here lower cost, unrealistically low `Rows` count and/or `INDEX ACCESS`,
than this is the cause of the problem of the **underestimating of the cost**. *So don't worry the old cost are too low, not the new one too high!*

The next step is the access on both  buyer and supplier. To get the answer you must provide
additional information.

How selective is the supplier filter?

I.e. if the predicate `buyer_identifier='GC84338293AA'` returns say 5M records, how may records return the predicate with both columns?

`buyer_identifier='GC84338293AA' and supplier_identifier='GC75987723HT'`

Is it 4M or 100 records?

If the complete predicate returns only few records than the local index on supplier is OK.

If it returns large number of rows (say the quarter of the partition) - you should stay on FULL PARTITION SCAN and not use it. 
This is similar to my comment on the non partitioned table.

**Estimation of the supplier cardinality**

In case that the column SUPPLIER contains a skewed data (which may fool the CBO to calulate improper cost) you may define explicitely histogram in this column.

I used this statement statement, that calculates the histogram on full data (100% is important for highly skewed data) and for the table and partition.

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>user,tabname=>'TAB_LP',granularity=>'all',estimate_percent => 100,METHOD_OPT => 'for columns SUPPLIER_ID size 254');
```

This worked for my test data, i.e. for supplier with low cardinality an index access was opened (on local no-prefixed index) and for huge suppliers a full partition scan was used.

Comment: @Manu Let me know about the distribution of the buyers and suppliers and re-formulate the problem (not using optimizer cost) to be able provide
further advice.  Anyway a very interesting question!

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.I tried with the **buyer_identifier** as a filter and as you explained all the cost are less for partitioned table. But, the moment I am using additional **supplier_identifier** as filter, the cost is going for a toss. But, with global index, the cost is decreasing but, not like non-partitioned cost. In db supplier document count can vary, i.e some one can have 1/4th records or more of total records.

Comment: @Manu, once again, don't be scared from the CBO costs:). I added the notion of histogram, this should help to calculate the plan and cost more appropriate. Pls re-check my answer.

Comment: @Marmite-Bomber. You should **always** use AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE for estimate_percent when gathering stats. Why? Because this uses a newer, faster and more accurate stats gathering algorithm. AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE is also a requirement for some of the other advanced stats gathering techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Local partitioned index using this script.

```
CREATE INDEX PO_HEADER_LOCAL_IDX ON PO_HEADER_LP
(BUYER_IDENTIFIER, SUPPLIER_IDENTIFIER)
LOCAL (
       PARTITION GC66287246AA,  
       PARTITION GC43837235JK,  
       PARTITION GC84338293AA,  
       PARTITION DEFAULTBUID
      );
```

Also it is recommended to gather statistics of the newly created partition table using this script:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('SCHEMA Name','PO_HEADER_LP');
```

Now you can generate the execution plan again of the following SQL:

```
select * from po_header_lp where buyer_identifier= 'GC84338293AA' and supplier_identifier='GC75987723HT';
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Already tried this Local Pre-fixed Index approch. But, it's even taking more cost & execution of query time.

Comment: As per your script you created local partitioned index using one column(SUPPLIER_IDENTIFIER). Do you try using both columns((BUYER_IDENTIFIER, SUPPLIER_IDENTIFIER)) as I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I have created local pre-fixed index using (BUYER_IDENTIFIER, SUPPLIER_IDENTIFIER), but it's not at all using the index instead using full table scan

Comment: Is the table(PO_HEADER_LP) statistics  up to date?

Comment: Gathered Table Statics. Now, it's using Index, but cost/time is more than the normal global index.

Comment: When use nonprefixed local index partition_start and partition_stop showed 3. Now generate execution plan and let us know how many partitions the optimizer scan?